# Reshuffling the order statistic of uniform at midpoint

Tags: probability-theory, order-statistics

Let $U_1,\dots,U_n$ be i.i.d. drawn from the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and let $U_{(1)} \le U_{(2)} \le \dots \le U_{(n)}$ be their order statistics. Assume that $n$ is even and that we take $U_{(1)} \le U_{(2)} \le \dots \le U_{(n/2)}$ and randomly permute them to get $\tilde U_1, \tilde U_2, \dots, \tilde U_{n/2}$. This way we get an IID sequence. Intuitively, each $\tilde U_i$ should have a distribution close to uniform $[0,1/2]$. But how far away the actual distribution is from uniform $[0,1/2]$? In particular, it seems that the support of this new distribution is still $[0,1]$, but can we control the tail of it past $1/2$?

EDIT: As has been pointed out, $(\tilde U_i)$ won't have the distribution of an IID sequence, but that of an exchangeable one. I am mainly interested in estimates for large $n$. (It would also be interesting to see how far from IID they are for large $n$, if there is a way to estimate that).

Comment: If $n=4$, the distribution of $(U_{(1)},U_{(2)})$ has density $12(1-u_2)^2$ on $0<u_1<u_2<1$ hence the distribution of $(X,Y)=(\tilde U_{1},\tilde U_{2})$ has density $6(1-\max(x,y))^2$ on $0<x<1$, $0<y<1$. **This is not the density of an i.i.d. sample** (the same applies to every $n\geqslant4$). The common density of $X$ and $Y$ is $2(1-x)^2(1+2x)$ on $0<x<1$, which has $18.75\%$ of its mass on the interval $(.5,1)$.

Comment: @Did, thanks for pointing out my mistake! You are right. I should have said they have an exchangeable distribution which hopefully is correct.

Comment: "It would be also interesting to see how far from IID they are for large $n$, if there is a way to do that" You could try to expand the computations in my comment to the general case of $n$ even.

Comment: @Did, yes, thanks. I will think about it. It is an open ended question. I do guess that the distribution becomes close to that of an IID sequence of uniform$(0,1/2)$ variables. I wonder if there are some general results that can be leveraged without explicitly computing the density.